# Serving static images from S3 is really slow for some reason (Flask, Heroku)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, flask

I have a code that generates an image from an input of text.
When I serve it in my localhost and from my OS (files are stored in the file system in the static folder) it takes about 2 seconds for it to show which means that the code that generates the image doesn't take a lot of time.

I have an endpoint that takes the parameter text and creates that image, than uploads it to an S3-Bucket and then returns this image from the bucket.

This process takes a lot of time! about 10 seconds from clicking on the button that should display the image until it is seen.

I am afraid i'm doing something wrong.

Images are uploaded with a CacheControl='max-age=604800' parameter which means they should be cached.

I don't upload them as gzip, should I? They are about 250 kb per image. is gzip needed? will it change the speed?
I also don't use Cloudfront because it's expensive, but I don't think this is a must.

Any ideas?

Comment: CloudFront + S3 costs about the same as S3 alone.  But, you technically shouldn't "need" it.    Gzipping also should not be needed for images.

Comment: Ok so any idea why it takes so long? Uplading is standart, just a put object function call that puts the image in the folder inside the bucket and serving is just return redirect(url_for('static', filename=path))

Comment: No idea yet... where are you, relative to the bucket?  What do you observe if you download images that are already in the bucket?

Comment: I am very far relative to the bucket. But my app will get traffic from all over the world so I don't think my location is a function for this. will Cloudfront solve this? I don't download images, I display them (changed content type to image/jpeg). For some reason it is still slow although they should be cached.

Comment: It is certainly worth trying CloudFront, if for no other reason than curiosity.